# Twilio chat demo js issue

Tags: javascript, twilio

I was working on twilio chat demo js,once after login successfully i am getting repeated channels on left side.hope there is a problem with the sdk,can anyone help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Is this the demo application? Or have you build it yourself? What is the code that lists the channels?

Comment: its a demo application provided by twilio programmable chat javascript SDK

Comment: @philnash it's coming from here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in demo application code, not in SDK itself, that was causing channel duplication while displaying them in the left pane.

It was fixed as part of moving to 1.0 GA version of JS SDK library (see [commit](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js/commit/c257e15c7322770177c5e37ada1ab51ca6a7a9dd) for the details).

Pulling latest demo application code should resolve your issue.